# I need help for storing the splitted characters of two integers into each other by character

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    while (a > 0) {
        int digit = a % 10;
        //printf("%d ",digit); for testing
        a = a - digit;
        a /= 10;
    }
    while (b > 0) {
        int digit = b % 10;
        //printf("%d ",digit); for testing
        b = b - digit;
        b /= 10;
    }
}
```

This code takes two integers with the same lengths(a,b), splits them into their characters, now the question is how to print it like this for example(a=123 , b= 798 --> result = 17-29-38

Comment: You need to save the digits in arrays.

Comment: Do you have to read them as integers? It will be easier if you read them as strings.

Comment: Yeah it has to be an integer because an automatic system gives inputs and checks for results and grades us...thanks for the answer

Comment: How would checking the results tell whether you're reading it with `%d` or `%s`?

Comment: I actually got a hundred with some edits on the code and adding a if-while-else part to check if one or both of the numbers are zeroes and I got a 100(thanks again), so I'm pretty sure the inputs were integers not strings. @Barmar

Comment: If you are using scanf to read the data, then that data is a string.  The whole purpose of scanf is to convert the string to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the digits in arrays. Then you can loop over the arrays to print the digits at the end.

Also, you don't need to subtract `digit` before dividing by 10, since division discards the remainder.

```
# include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDIGITS 20

int main(){
    int a,b;
    int adigits[MAXDIGITS], bdigits[MAXDIGITS];
    int digits = 0;

    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    while (a > 0) {
        int digit = a % 10;
        //printf("%d ",digit); for testing
        adigits[digits++] = digit;
        a /= 10;
    }
    digits = 0;
    while (b > 0) {
        int digit = b % 10;
        //printf("%d ",digit); for testing
        bdigits[digits++] = digit;
        b /= 10;
    }
    while (--digits >= 0) {
        printf("%d%d", adigits[digits], bdigits[digits]);
        if (digits != 0) {
            putchar('-');
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is strings, and there is no point in converting those strings to integers just to change them back.  Just work on the data directly.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stddef.h>                                                                
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct buffer {                                                                    
        char *start;                                                               
        char *end;                                                                 
        size_t cap;                                                                
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
void push(int c, struct buffer *);                                                 
int pop(struct buffer *);                                                          
void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *offsetp);                 
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(void)                                                                         
{                                                                                  
        struct buffer a = {0};                                                     
        struct buffer b = {0};                                                     
        int c;                                                                     
                                                                                   
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace(c) ) {                           
                push(c, &a);                                                       
        }                                                                          
        while(isspace(c = getchar())) {                                            
                ;                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        ungetc(c, stdin);                                                          
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {                                          
                push(c, &b);                                                       
        }                                                                          
        while( (c = pop(&a)) != EOF ) {                                            
                putchar(c);                                                        
                if( (c = pop(&b)) != EOF ) {                                       
                        putchar(c);                                                
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        while( (c = pop(&b)) != EOF ) {                                            
                putchar(c);                                                        
        }                                                                          
                                                                                   
        return 0;                                                                  
}

int                                                                                
pop(struct buffer *a)                                                              
{                                                                                  
        return (a->start < a->end) ? *a->start++ : EOF;                            
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void                                                                               
push(int c, struct buffer *b)                                                      
{                                                                                  
        if( b->start == NULL ) {                                                   
                b->end = b->start = xrealloc(NULL, b->cap = 8, 1, NULL);           
        } else if( b->end >= b->start + b->cap ) {                                 
                b->start = xrealloc(b->start, b->cap *= 2, 1, &b->end);            
        }                                                                          
        *b->end++ = c;                                                             
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void *                                                                             
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *offsetp)                         
{                                                                                  
        ptrdiff_t offset;                                                          
        void **iterator = offsetp;                                                 
        if( iterator != NULL ) {                                                   
                offset = *iterator - buf;                                          
        }                                                                          
        buf = realloc(buf, num * siz);                                             
        if( buf == NULL ) {                                                        
                perror("realloc");                                                 
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        if( iterator != NULL ) {                                                   
                *iterator = buf + offset;                                          
        }                                                                          
        return buf;                                                                
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though because I'm pretty much a beginner I understood nothing of your code!!!